# SecurityError on drawImage() canvas function only in Edge

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, microsoft-edge

I have trying to retrieve photos from a different domain and then add it to a formdata to send it to my API. I am using canvas to do it. It works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome and in IE. But in Edge I have an error in the Console :  SCRIPT5022: SecurityError and its points out to context.drawImage(). The post request is not even trigered.

I have tried to switch from crossOrigins anonymous to use-credentials but it doesn't change a thing. I have incorporated the onload function in my code but then the formdata sent to my API doesn't have a trace of the pictures.

```
var nbSelected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected").length;
for (i=0; i<nbSelected;i++){
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      var image = document.getElementsByClassName("selected")[i];
      image.setAttribute("crossOrigin","anonymous");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

      canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
      canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
      //in Edge the error points out to the following line
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      var dataUrlCanvas = canvas.toDataURL('image/png',1.0);
      var otherBlob = dataURLtoBlob(dataUrlCanvas);
      const filename = "file"+i+".png";
      const file = new Blob([otherBlob],{type:"image/png"});
      formData.append(filename, file, filename);
   }
```

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Edge version are you using? Please check the image extension, from your code I guess it is a .png file, right? I have created [a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bt3kzup5/) on my side (using Microsoft Edge 44 version), it works well on my side, you could check it.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try it ! I have this on Edge Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 and Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134